# Hiding Section/Slide Arrows on Pages - Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm working on a website using fullpage.js:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

The first problem I had is that I need to hide the arrows once it falls into the last section and/or slide. ie. if you're on the far right slide, my hope is it will hide the right arrow. Top section, top arrow is hidden, etc.

I've tried quite a bit to make it work, I'm still learning javascript so forgive me if I'm way off, but I was hoping this was close:

```
    function hideArrowUp() {
        if(index == 1){
            $('.arrowUp').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.arrowUp').show();
        }
    }

    function hideArrowDown(anchorlink) {
        if(index == 3){
            $('.arrowDown').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.arrowDown').show();
        }
    }
```

And I was hope to prevent horizontal slides from repeating/rolling-over, not sure if that's an easy one.

Please and thanks!

Comment: You got it answered in the github issues forum: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the plugin callbacks such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave` to remove the arrow by using javascript or by adding a class.

You can also use the class of type `fp-viewing-xxxx` added to your body element to apply one or another style.

Take a look at the [demo page of fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage). In that case you can inspect the DOM and see how the `body` gets the class `fp-viewing-4thpage` applied when reaching the last section. That's because it is using the anchor `4thpage` as you can see in the URL (#4thpage).

Therefore you can do something like the following in your CSS stylesheet:

```
.fp-viewing-4thpage .myArrow{
    display:none;
}
```

Remember the demo page and many others examples are available [in the downloaded files](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Thanks very much for the help again!
I hid the boxes as you suggested with CSS. I think I need to do a little more work with Javascript before I try and figure the afterload and onleave out. But for now, CSS can do visually what I want!

Answer (score 5):

Now You can to this with javascript options.

When u call the full page function on a div. Just set the option control arrow to false.

```
//call full page function with options.
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors:['anchor-1','anchor-2'],
        controlArrows: false,
        });
```

Regards
Alex